# require multiple modules/routes in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to split my routes into several files.

A single route contains this code

```
module.exports = function(app){

  app.get('/page', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page');
  });

}
```

and they get stored in my `routes.js`. I want to require them once ...

```
const routes = [
  "page1",
  "page2",
  "page3"
];

module.exports = function(app){

for(var i = 0; routes.length; i++){
  require('./Routes/' + routes[i])(app);
}

}
```

my server.js would require the `routes.js` module

```
require('./Server/routes')(app);
```

but when running the server, the current route in the loop is undefined and the server will run into an endless loop.

How can I handle this / require multiple modules in my `routes.js` by looping through them.

---

**EDIT**

I just have a bad for loop.. stupid me

Comment: Your `for` loop is incorrect.

Comment: oh .. my bad .. wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
for(var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++){
    require('./Routes/' + routes[i])(app);
}
```